# How to add a band to xarray dataset using rioxarray

Tags: python, merge, rioxarray, xarray

I have two datasets, both rasters, which I would like to combine into 1 raster. This should not be difficult, but I'm having a hard time.. Both have the same extent/resolution etc.
One raster has 231 bands, the other raster has 1 band. I would like to create a raster with 232 bands. Below is some information on both rasters.

I have been looking into the `merge_datasets()` command, but no luck yet. Any clues?

```
<xarray.DataArray (band: 231, y: 1234, x: 1234)>
array([[[nan, nan, nan, ..., nan, nan, nan],
        [nan, nan, nan, ..., nan, nan, nan],
        [nan, nan, nan, ..., nan, nan, nan],
        ...,
        [nan, nan, nan, ..., nan, nan, nan],
        [nan, nan, nan, ..., nan, nan, nan],
        [nan, nan, nan, ..., nan, nan, nan]],

       [[nan, nan, nan, ..., nan, nan, nan],
        [nan, nan, nan, ..., nan, nan, nan],
        [nan, nan, nan, ..., nan, nan, nan],
        ...,
        [nan, nan, nan, ..., nan, nan, nan],
        [nan, nan, nan, ..., nan, nan, nan],
        [nan, nan, nan, ..., nan, nan, nan]],

       [[nan, nan, nan, ..., nan, nan, nan],
        [nan, nan, nan, ..., nan, nan, nan],
        [nan, nan, nan, ..., nan, nan, nan],
        ...,
...
        ...,
        [nan, nan, nan, ..., nan, nan, nan],
        [nan, nan, nan, ..., nan, nan, nan],
        [nan, nan, nan, ..., nan, nan, nan]],

       [[nan, nan, nan, ..., nan, nan, nan],
        [nan, nan, nan, ..., nan, nan, nan],
        [nan, nan, nan, ..., nan, nan, nan],
        ...,
        [nan, nan, nan, ..., nan, nan, nan],
        [nan, nan, nan, ..., nan, nan, nan],
        [nan, nan, nan, ..., nan, nan, nan]],

       [[nan, nan, nan, ..., nan, nan, nan],
        [nan, nan, nan, ..., nan, nan, nan],
        [nan, nan, nan, ..., nan, nan, nan],
        ...,
        [nan, nan, nan, ..., nan, nan, nan],
        [nan, nan, nan, ..., nan, nan, nan],
        [nan, nan, nan, ..., nan, nan, nan]]])
Coordinates:
  * y            (y) float64 39.01 39.02 39.02 39.02 ... 39.34 39.34 39.34 39.34
  * x            (x) float64 -118.8 -118.8 -118.8 ... -118.4 -118.4 -118.4
  * band         (band) int32 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 ... 225 226 227 228 229 230 231
    spatial_ref  int32 0
Attributes:
    scale_factor:  1.0
    add_offset:    0.0


<xarray.DataArray (y: 1234, x: 1234)>
array([[ 2.55955   ,  2.55955   ,  2.55955   , ..., 26.846706  ,
        19.290512  , 18.555965  ],
       [ 1.511336  ,  1.193543  ,  1.511336  , ..., 20.782856  ,
        16.041739  , 21.056656  ],
       [ 1.1935476 ,  0.        ,  0.        , ..., 10.154096  ,
        11.940413  , 17.73191   ],
       ...,
       [ 3.029245  ,  3.029245  ,  1.1990428 , ...,  5.2065864 ,
         3.027078  , 27.63241   ],
       [ 0.        ,  1.5156854 ,  2.2077734 , ...,  5.1539397 ,
         4.5386004 , 19.661118  ],
       [ 1.8543341 ,  0.92740995,  0.92740995, ...,  5.1539497 ,
         3.7047918 , 13.450604  ]], dtype=float32)
Coordinates:
  * y            (y) float64 39.01 39.02 39.02 39.02 ... 39.34 39.34 39.34 39.34
  * x            (x) float64 -118.8 -118.8 -118.8 ... -118.4 -118.4 -118.4
    band         int32 1
    spatial_ref  int32 0
Attributes:
    scale_factor:  1.0
    add_offset:    0.0
    long_name:     slope
```

Comment: Have you tried this: https://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/generated/xarray.merge.html ?

Answer (score 2):

In case it's still useful, I found a method (although it's time consuming, and probably more so with your raster):

```
import rioxarray as rxr
import xarray as xr
import os

def merge_images(raster1, raster2, my_dir):
    out_name = raster1.replace(".tif", "_new.tif")  # create new name

    # opens raster as an xarray dataarray
    my_raster = rxr.open_rasterio(os.path.join(my_dir, raster1))
    my_raster.name = 'new_raster'  # name array to allow for merge
    raster_toAdd = rxr.open_rasterio(raster2)
    raster_toAdd["band"] = raster_toAdd["band"] + 231  # change band value
    raster2.name = 'new_raster'  # use the same name as above

    merged = xr.merge([my_raster, raster_toAdd])
    
    # add slope to list of long names; reassign all to new list
    new_long_names = list(merged.attrs['long_name']) + ['slope']
    merged.attrs['long_name'] = tuple(new_long_names)

    # remove spatial_ref, to allow for rewriting later
    if 'spatial_ref' in list(merged.coords):
        merged = merged.drop('spatial_ref')

    # Make copy of merged
    merged_copy = merged.copy()
    merged_copy['band'] = list(merged_copy.attrs['long_name'])

    # create a blank dataset to write bands to
    xa_dataset = xr.Dataset()
    for band in merged_copy['band'].values:
        xa_dataset[band] = merged_copy['new_image'].sel(band = band)
    xa_dataset.rio.to_raster(os.path.join(my_dir, out_name))
```